# Add header/footer in addHTML method of jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I am using `addHTML` method of jsPDF to generate PDF. I want to add header/Footer in each PDF pages.

Is it possible to add header/footer in `addHTML` method of jsPDF?

If yes, then please provide the example of same.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this??...I am stuck up at the same problem :(

Comment: Yes.. I modified the source file.. Please check addHtml function in jspdf.js file: example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WAechrtTMBIdyfhkMU7X?p=preview